# Помогите разобрать json

Tags: json, swift

Получаю вот такой JSON:

```
{
    "deleted": false,
    "updatedAt": "2018-01-06T21:00:58.764Z",
    "createdAt": "2018-01-06T21:00:58.764Z",
    "version": "AAAAAAAADZE=",
    "id": "0aa47d9fa01c4a5dace87ca8c2b02d01",
    "lessonId": "8686946ee30a49e69c35718f5d27ee26",
    "type": "choose right answer",
    "jsonText": "{\"ChooseRightAnswer\":[{\"title\":\"Сколько пальцев у человека на одной руке?\"},{\"wrongAnswer\":\"10\"},{\"wrongAnswer\":\"12\"},{\"rightAnswer\":\"5\"},{\"wrongAnswer\":\"13\"},{\"wrongAnswer\":\"12\"}]}",
    "name": "Сколько пальцев у человека на одной руке? "
}
```

Как на Swift 4 можно получить все содержание `jsonText`?

Вот код

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://teachmeserv.azurewebsites.net/tables/pattern/0aa47d9fa01c4a5dace87ca8c2b02d01") else { return }

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        guard let data = data else { return }
        print("data")

        do {
            let yourJsonObject = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as!  [String: AnyObject]
            if let jsonText = yourJsonObject["jsonText"] as? [String: [String: AnyObject]] {
                if let chooseRightAnswer = jsonText["ChooseRightAnswer"] {
                    if let title = chooseRightAnswer["title"] as? String{
                        print(title)
                    }
                    if let wrongAnswer = chooseRightAnswer["wrongAnswer"] as? String{
                        print(wrongAnswer)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

Comment: [Погуглить](http://bestkora.com/IosDeveloper/swift-4-parsim-json/) ?

Answer (score 3):

Когда ты получишь объект yourJsonObject можешь парсить следующим образом:

```
if let jsonText = yourJsonObject["jsonText"] as? [String: [String: AnyObject]] {
                if let chooseRightAnswer = jsonText["ChooseRightAnswer"] {
                    if let title = chooseRightAnswer["title"] as? String{
                        print(title)
                    }
                    if let wrongAnswer = chooseRightAnswer["wrongAnswer"] as? String{
                        print(wrongAnswer)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: вот проблема в том что под ключом  "jsonText" находится в формате String ( а как его преобразовать в Dictonary я не знаю

Comment: @samentyevtriboy, если бы был String, то были бы просто кавычки, а там фигурные скобки, это и есть Dictionary

Comment: Добавил код, но так и не получается извлеч данные (((